# Certbot SSL Certificate issue

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install the package CertBot Certificate but the system gives me an error
Here is what happens while yum is executing:

```
ca-certificates-2019.2.32-76.el7_7.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                | 399 kB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Updating   : ca-certificates-2019.2.32-76.el7_7.noarch                                                                                                                                        1/2
Error unpacking rpm package ca-certificates-2019.2.32-76.el7_7.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/ssl/certs: cpio: rename
  Verifying  : ca-certificates-2019.2.32-76.el7_7.noarch                                                                                                                                        1/2
ca-certificates-2018.2.22-70.0.el7_5.noarch was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : ca-certificates-2018.2.22-70.0.el7_5.noarch                                                                                                                                      2/2

Failed:
  ca-certificates.noarch 0:2018.2.22-70.0.el7_5                                                     ca-certificates.noarch 0:2019.2.32-76.el7_7

Complete!
Could not install OS dependencies. Aborting bootstrap!
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: did you run the command as root?

Comment: Yes. I did execute as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue in centos 7 server and this commands solved the error :

`$ mv /etc/ssl/certs /etc/ssl/certs.back`

`$ ln -s /etc/pki/tls/certs /etc/ssl/certs`

`$ yum update ca-certificate*`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by doing the following commands:

```
cd /etc/ssl
mv certs certs.saved
ln -s ../pki/tls/certs certs
```

After that the problem stopped happening and i was able to successfully install the certificate.